# Angular-nvd3/nvd3/d3 bar chart with multiple x axis groups

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I'm trying to find a way to create a grouped multi bar chart using d3 (preferably Angular-nvd3) that has multiple grouping levels on the x axis.

The end result would look something like the following (very simple) mock up:

[mock of bar chart with 2 x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxFI8.png)

Any solution would need use data binding to generate the correct axis labels i.e. no hard coding.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.